# Hide Status Bar In Non Rooted Device

Tags: android

How to hide status bar of tab in non rooted device? I am Using Android 4.0.4
 I used like this but it is not working for me...please suggest any solution

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // hide titlebar of application

    // must be before setting the layout

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // hide statusbar of Android

    // could also be done later

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,

            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: Do you mean the combined system bar at the bottom of the tablet UI? If so, there's no way to do it. Jelly Bean brings the two-bar UI to tablets which allows you to hide the top status bar and, temporarily, even the bottom/right navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

did you change the theme in android manifest like below,

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some researches about this problem a while ago.
 I could not find a solution to realize this in a non rooted device.
The best I could do is to dim the status bar as follows:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN ); // dim System bar
```

`FLAG_FULLSCREEN` flag doesnt do it anymore! Seems for security reasons, Google want it to always show, so that the user can press home button, etc ...
I am still wondering how applications like [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en) have made it possible.
Hope this helps!